# Scaled down batch of soda syphon batter

Tags: batter, soda

I want to make a smaller batch of a soda syphon batter recipe as a trial.  The batter involves flour, vodka, honey and lager, and is put into a CO2 soda syphon.
The full batch is too much for a trial run (300g of Vodka)
Can I scale it down or does that mess up the working of the syphon?  The full recipe calls for three charges, can I do 1/3 of the batter with one charge?  Or do I still use the three charges.  I’m not sure of the science here

Answer (score 2):

Generally with a 1L siphon it’s advised to use 2 or 3 charges. If you scale down your ingredients, you’ll create a much larger gap in the canister, this would mean you’d have to use even more charges which is not really safe at all!

If you’d like to scale down your recipe, you should also scale down your canister size too. Try using 0.25 or 0.5 liter canisters I’d say.

Comment: You raise an excellent point.   The recipe does not state canister size!  Despite being by Heston!  But with 600ml of liquid and 400g of flour I’d say it would be 1L.  Since I have 500ml I can divide by 2.   That still leaves the question of how many charges.

Comment: You will not need more charges!  This may, in fact, be dangerous...exceeding the pressure limitations of the canister!!  Scale down.  Use the canister you have...same recommended charge for the size canister.

Comment: @moscafj you’re right I added a safety note

Comment: @Rflack, for a 500 ml one, you should charge with one.